# Toggle Button in CustomList View

Tags: android

I have a customlist view with Toggle Buttons for all the rows. I have an onlick listner for ToggleButton and I am trying to set the status of all toggle buttons in the listview to false except the one that I have preseed. I have posted the code for the adapter below. Please help me with this.

To make it much more simple, I have to set the ToggleButton state to True when pressed/clicked and all other toggle button states to False. Moreover like a Radio group button. Please advise.

```
package Test.in.example.testairlight;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class PaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PaModel> {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DBHelper dbH;
    private ArrayList<PaModel> objects;


    public PaAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<PaModel> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View v = convertView;
        final Context cc=parent.getContext();

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pa_list_item, null);
        }

        PaModel i = objects.get(position);

        if (i != null) {

            TextView ttd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.devicelocation);
            final TextView mtd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.deviceid);
            TextView dzone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtzonedetail);
            final ToggleButton togglePA = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.togglePA);
            final ToggleButton toggleAlert = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleAlert);
            final ToggleButton toggleListen = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleListen);


            if (ttd != null){
                ttd.setText(i.getDevicelocation());
            }

            if (mtd != null){
                mtd.setText(String.valueOf(i.getDeviceid()));
            }



        toggleListen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //// Set Everything to OFF State
                //// Turn ON only the active Item



            }
        });

    ////// Listen Button







        if (dzone !=null){
            dzone.setText(i.getDevicezonedetail());

        }


                    }


        return v;
    }




}
```

Comment: Do you want to set all the buttons in just the listitem (where a toggleButton was clicked) to false, or all the buttons all over the list?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
toggleListen.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new ToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                       // do whatever you want here
                       togglePA.setChecked(false);
                       toggleAlert.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want to set all the buttons of the list to false, or just the buttons in the current listitem.
So let's face the first:

1. Set all the Buttons in the whole list to false (except the clicked one):

You could start by making a two-dimensional ArrayList of ToggleButtons like this in your adapter:

```
ArrayList<ToggleButton[]> tButtons = new ArrayList<ToggleButton[]>();
```

So, there is an ArrayList of ToggleButton-Arrays. Each ToggleButton[] consists of three ToggleButton-objects. The number of ToggleButton-Arrays in the ArrayList is undefined.

Now, you have to set your ToggleButtons into the ArrayList, inside of getView():

```
//other code here
final ToggleButton togglePA = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.togglePA);
final ToggleButton toggleAlert = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleAlert);
final ToggleButton toggleListen = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleListen);
ToggleButton[] tButtonsInListItem;
    if(tButtons.get(position) == null) {
        tButtonsInListItem = new ToggleButton[3];
        tButtons.set(position, tButtonsInListItem);
    } else {
        tButtonsInListItem = tButtons.get(position);
    }
tButtonsInListItem[0] = togglePA;
tButtonsInListItem[1] = toggleAlert;
tButtonsInListItem[2] = toggleListen;
```

Now you've got all your ToggleButtons ready for modification!

So here's the code:

```
toggleListen.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new ToggleButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                for(ToggleButton[] tButtonsArray : tButtons) {
                    for(ToggleButton tButton : tButtonsArray) {
                        if(tButton == buttonView) {
                            tButton.setChecked(true);
                        } else {
                            tButton.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

If you want to just set the buttons of the same listitem to false, please let me know :)

Edit:
Perhaps I should say this is not the best solution in my opinion.
I actually think you should have the data (true / false) somewhere in your model.
Then you could just manipulate the model, and put the model-data back to the view (the ToggleButtons) to show.